# Automatic method generation based on parent pure virtual methods

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

I have a problem like the next one:

I have a library that exposes a factory interface: all methods are virtual but the create() one, that will return an implementation.

Now I want to wrap it in my class, mainly to add some methods and do a "more RAII" destruction. My class will have a pointer to the implementation, and will forward most method to it.

Sadly, this forces me to write every pure virtual method only to forward it to the child class. I've tried all sort or template+macros tricks, but (it seems that) I can't override a parent's method with templates, I can't "template" the method name...

This is the naive working solution I have so far:

```
// lib.h

#include <memory>

class C;

class F {
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual int bar(int *) = 0;
    virtual void close() = 0;
    F *create(class C*);
};

// my realm
class I : public F {
public:
    I(C *c) {
        f.reset(F::create(c));
    }

~I() {
        f->close();
    }

    int mybar(int *);
    void foo() override {
        f->foo();
    }
    int bar(int *i) override {
        return f->bar(i);
    }

    private:
    std::unique_ptr<F> f;
};
```

I CAN'T edit the `lib.h`, only the I class. Is there a way to generate the override methods automatically, so it's not need to

Comment: Why do you inherit from `F` but also hold a pointer to it?

Comment: `F` is used by others methods in the library and I would like to use my implementation directly with no need of expose `I::f` pointer. To inherit is not really a restriction, but to be able to use I that way is.

Comment: You can inherit from a helper class that does this for you. It can take a reference to your pointer and use it to call its methods.

Comment: I'm confused - what is the purpose of `I`?  you could do the same by just just using a `std::unique_ptr<F>` rather than an I.

Comment: The point of I is to call close() before object deletion (I can achieve it with custom destructor of unique ptr) and to extend (wrapping) the F instance that library return to me, that can vary between library version (with the method mybar in the example).

Comment: @0x499602d2 but then I would have to implement every pure virtual function on the helper class manually, isn't?